# Select * in mongo id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I got this query:

```
User.collection.aggregate([
      {"$project" => {
        "dayOfMonth" => {"$dayOfMonth" => "$created_time"},
        "month" => {"$month" => "$created_time"},
        "year" => {"$year" => "$created_time"},
      }},
      {"$group" => {
        "_id" => { "dayOfMonth" => "$dayOfMonth", "month" => "$month", "year" => "$year"},
        "Total" => {"$sum" => 1}
      }},
      {"$sort" => {
        "created_at" => -1
      }}
    ])
```

My user table has username and fullname which I need,

I did something like

```
User.collection.aggregate([
          {"$project" => {
            "dayOfMonth" => {"$dayOfMonth" => "$created_at"},
            "month" => {"$month" => "$created_at"},
            "year" => {"$year" => "$created_at"},
            "username" => "$username"
          }},
          {"$group" => {
            "_id" => { "dayOfMonth" => "$dayOfMonth", "month" => "$month", "year" => "$year"},
            "Total" => {"$sum" => 1}
          }},
          {"$sort" => {
            "created_at" => -1
          }}
        ])
```

but it doesn't work and gives same result like above, doesn't print username, any ideas ?
My goal is get username, after grouping by created at date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.collection.aggregate([
          {"$project" => {
            "dayOfMonth" => {"$dayOfMonth" => "$created_at"},
            "month" => {"$month" => "$created_at"},
            "year" => {"$year" => "$created_at"},
            "username" => "$username"
          }},
          {"$group" => {
            "_id" => { "dayOfMonth" => "$dayOfMonth", "month" => "$month", "year" => "$year"},
            "Total" => {"$sum" => 1},
            "username" => {"$first" => "$username"}
          }},
          {"$sort" => {
            "created_at" => -1
          }}
        ])
```